# Faça um programa que calcule o valor de H*S, sendo:

Tags: java

[image: Problema em questão]

Tava usando essa solução baseado em um código de um amigo:
porém estamos incertos sobre o resultado.

```
        double h = 0;
        double n = 4;
        
        double s = 0;
        double n1 = 36;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) {
            h = h +  (double) 1/i;
            
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <=n1; i++) {
            s = s - (double) 1/i;
        }
        
        double total;
        
        total = h*s;
            
            System.out.println("S: " + s);
            System.out.println("H: " + h);
            
            System.out.println("Valor total: " + total);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare que para calcular `h` e `s` você está sempre somando (ou subtraindo) `1/i` (ou seja, 1 dividido por `i`). Mas repare na definição que o numerador não é sempre `1`, ele também tem que mudar. E no caso do `s`, o sinal também muda a cada termo (uma hora subtrai, depois soma, subtrai, soma, etc).

Então você tem que controlar tanto o numerador quanto o denominador.

No caso do `h`, temos 50 termos: o denominador varia de 1 a 50, e o numerador aumenta de 2 em 2.
E no `s`, são apenas 10 termos: o numerador varia de 1 a 10, e o denominador é o numerador ao quadrado. E temos que fazer o sinal se alternar também:

```
double h = 0.0;
double numerador = 1.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    h += numerador / i;
    numerador += 2;
}
double s = 0.0;
double sinal = 1.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    s += (sinal * i) / (i * i);
    sinal *= -1;
}
System.out.println("h=" + h);
System.out.println("s=" + s);
System.out.println("h * s=" + h * s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Os somatorios estao errados. Observe que `H = 1/1 + 3/2 + 5/3...`, ou seja enquanto o numerador da fração(o de cima) começa em 1 e vai aumentando de 2 em 2, o denominador vai aumento de 1 em 1. Fique atento para o fato de o numerador ser uma unidade menor do que o dobro do denomindor, esse resultado é obtido assim (`i * 2 - 1`).

Observe na definicao do problema do S que quando o numerador for impar voce deve somar e quando for um numero par voce deve subtrair.Entao verifque essa condicao com `i % 2 == 0`, se for false entao `subtraia`, pois o numerador é par, caso contrario `some`. em S o denominador é igual a quadrado do numerador `Math.pow(i, 2)`.

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double h = 0;
    double n = 50;
        
    double s = 0;
    double n1 = 10;
        
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
      h = h +  (double) (i * 2 - 1)/(i); 
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <=n1; i++) {
      if(i % 2 == 0){ 
        s = s - (double) i/Math.pow(i, 2);
      }
      else{
        s = s + (double) i/Math.pow(i, 2);
      }
    }
        
    double total;
        
    total = h*s;
            
    System.out.println("S: " + s);
    System.out.println("H: " + h);
            
    System.out.println("Valor total: " + total);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu conferi com meu professor, e ele confirmou que é uma solução correta, estava quebrando a cabeça com esse problema há bastante tempo, tive que recorrer a ajuda externa. :)